# WooCommerce Javascript Product Page Button Edit

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have no experience writing or editing Javascript but I need to add a Continue Shopping button to my WooCommerce Product Pages. I found a string of code that got the link to show up, however it doesn't have a class so I cannot move or edit it, I would also prefer it to be a button than just a link.

How would I add styles to this element using CSS? Can I give it an ID and/or class?

This is the javascript I have currently in my function.php file

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', create_function( '', 'echo "<a href=\"http://store.lovesomelashes.com\">Continue Shopping</a>";' ), 35 );
```

And here is a link to an example product page. http://store.lovesomelashes.com/product/c-curl-synthetic-mink-eyelash-extensions/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code that you have isn't javascript. It's actually php and it's used to add an action (anonymous function in this case) to the woocommerce hook for product details (woocommerce_single_product_summary).

And as a simple response to your question, yes you can add a class to your link to style it and make it look like your other buttons. Change your code like this to add the class:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', create_function( '', 'echo "<a href=\"http://store.lovesomelashes.com\" class=\"my-button\">Continue Shopping</a>";' ), 35 );
```

my-button is your class, you can style it on your style file.